# A TextBox with float values can accept null value also

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to create textbox that accepts float values or blank value. We are using XAML/UWP with C#, and also using Microsoft UI Toolkit, for floating value validation. We have two way binding with our entity class. This Entity class is use to fetch/update database. If we have no value for our float it shows "0" in textbox, see below image-

[image]

When I set this textbox to blank and press "Tab" key

[image]

like this, it generates an error

> The parameter is incorrect. The value cannot be converted to type Single`

and the application crashes.

When I convert `float` to `float?` in our C# class and rebuild the project, it gives compilation error-

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'float?'" on XAML Textbox where binding code is written.

XAML Code -

```
....
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
....
<TextBox  
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Dynamic"
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationType="Custom"
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+"
    Text="{x:Bind VM.percentage, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you share your xaml code?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I share my XAML Code in question, please see my question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The parameter is incorrect. The value cannot be converted to type Single`

The problem you have set percentage as `null`, But the float type never could be set null value. For this scenario we need use  `IValueConverter` when bind value two-way model.

```
public class FloatToString : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if ((float)value == 0f)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((string)value == string.Empty)
            {
                return 0f;
            }
            return float.Parse(value as string);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0f;      
        }

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:FloatToString x:Key="FlotToStringConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>

   <TextBox Height="44" Text="{x:Bind Percentage, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource FlotToStringConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the C# class your binding the Text and the code behind file for the page or window associated with your xaml here I would first say to try the following. If this does not work there are a few other things you could try.

First the exception is being thrown because a value of [string.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=netframework-4.8) cannot be converted into a single precision floating integer(float).

There are a couple approaches you can take to this based on the information provided I think you could simply use the [Textbox.TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textchanged) event as you see here below. In addition you will also want to add a name to you textbox below so you can access that field declared in the xaml in the code behind via the x:Name attribute.

```
....
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
....
<TextBox x:Name="yourTextBoxName" 
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Dynamic"
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationType="Custom"
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+"
    Text="{x:Bind VM.percentage, Mode=TwoWay}"
    TextChanged="Textbox_OnTextChanged" />
```

Then you'll want to add the following event handler declared above to your code-behind file.

```
private void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourTextBoxName.Text))
        yourTextBoxName.Text = 0;

    // Additional logic if needed.
}
```

If I'm not mistaken you already should be using the [float.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=netframework-4.8) method or perhaps the [float.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method in one of those c# files as well.

If this interferes with your binding I may need to see a small snippet of the C# as well to be able to help. This approach should allow you to always see 0 as well.

if you prefer blank you could simply change the logic in the event handler slightly or better yet for that case rather than using the TextBox.TextChanged event you could instead use the [TextBox.KeyUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keyup) or [TextBox.KeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown) events like so.

```
private void TextBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourTextBoxName.Text))
            yourTextBoxName.Text = 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
private void TextBox_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourTextBoxName.Text))
            yourTextBoxName.Text = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it difficult to implement when textboxes more than 4 on a single page...

Comment: Actually you would just use event handlers with different names as needed. So rather than TextBox_OnKeyUp you could name it TextBox1_OnKeyUp, TextBox2_OnKeyUp, and so on. You could also name the handlers specific to a type or based on functionality. Also I should point out that's three different ways you could do it based on preference/need as not enough details were provided initially in case that wasn't clear enough. That's really not even that many controls to implement on.